# Clear WPF report viewer in ActiveReports

Tags: wpf, activereports, grapecity

I would like to know how to clear the WPF report viewer in ActiveReports. All the articles suggest I assign null to Document property but no such property exists. LoadDocument method loads the report into the viewer but it doesn't take null as parameter. I thought passing null would clear the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `LoadDocument` method with an empty document to clear WPF viewer:

```
ReportViewer.LoadDocument(new GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Document.SectionDocument());
```

Comment: I ended up doing that in the end just forgot to post it as an answer. Good one!